# bat Файл не работает

Tags: windows, cmd

По идее bat файл должен выполнять последовательность команд. Вот содержимое bat файла:

```
 @echo off
    D:
    cd "D:\Visual Studio\VC\Auxiliary\Build"
    "vcvarsall.bat" x64
    cd ..\..\..\..
    cd CODE\code
    cl -Zi win32_handmade.cpp user32.lib gdi32.lib
```

Те кто знакомы с С++ поймут, что эти команды компилируют код и создают .exe, но почему-то не срабатывает, ХОТЯ если ввести эти команды в cmd вручную, то всё работает. Что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не

```
"vcvarsall.bat"
```

а

```
call vcvarsall.bat 64
```

Иначе управление передается `vcvarsall.bat` *безвозвратно*.

Я не знаю, как это будет работать с `call` - в том плане, что нет ли в `vcvarsall.bat` чего-то, что помешает дальнейшей работе, но без `call` по завершении `vcvarsall.bat` управление в вызывающую программу не возвращается.